# Running a sambashare with user configuration

Tags: systemd, samba

I've been trying to achieve this:

1. Use samba config file under `.config/smb.conf`

and

2. a service config file under `.config/systemd/user/smbd.service`

and

3. run `systemctl --user start smbd.service`

Yet the status fails, and all I get either from `systemctl --user status smbd.service` or `journalctl --user --e` is:

```
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]: [2021/05/22 15:26:48.756294,  0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1098(reopen_one_log)
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]:   reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]: [2021/05/22 15:26:48.756339,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1775(main)
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]:   smbd version 4.11.6-Ubuntu started.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]:   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2019
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: smbd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: Stopped Samba SMB Daemon.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: smbd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1582]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

I'm aware of this line `May 22 15:26:48 localhost.localdomain smbd[19674]:   reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied` but I've no idea where it's coming from as the samba config file clearly indicates `$HOME/logs/samba/log.%m`.

For completeness I paste the config file:

```
[global]

   workgroup = sm
   client min protocol = NT1
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = $HOME/logs/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

####### Authentication #######

   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes


[sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /home/sm/samba
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    directory mask = 0755
```

If necessary I can add the user config file for the service unit.
Any idea?

Comment: Change `$HOME` with full path can help?

Comment: @YetAnotherUser no luck even after reloading the daemon (although that should not matter here)

Comment: Also, when running systemctl status, it clearly shows: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --daemon --configfile /home/sm/.config/myconfs/smb.conf` so idk...@YetAnotherUser thanks for helping anyways

Comment: i guess the permissions could be changed for that folder but idk why this is happening